# How can I tell if my local Docker registry is up?

Tags: docker

I have started a local Docker registry with `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2` and it works fine for pushing and pulling. In a script that is going to pull from this local registry, I want to first test whether the registry is up. Is there any good way to do this short of trying a pull and catching the "Error while pulling image..." error?

Comment: First define "my local docker registry is up". Does that mean the host is listening on tcp/5000? Does that mean you can access a known docker registry API endpoint? Does that mean the known docker registry API endpoint returns an expected value?

Comment: Yes to all of the above. Basically, if I'm about to push or pull, is the registry ready for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not mention which OS you are using but you could do a request  to `/` for a 200 response or `/v2/` using the `401` response as OK.

so for Bash on Linux

```
status_code=$(curl -I -k -s https://<address>:5000/ | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
if [[ "$status_code" == "200" ]]; then
    # pull 
fi
```

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/registry/deploying.md) (Important/Required HTTP-Headers) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, this seems sensible. It works more sanely with `-m 5` in the `curl` command as well.